# Apply if and else to the condition which the data frame is or is not empty pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to apply new columns to a data frame if it is not empty. Let say `no_result` is the pandas data frame. If it is empty, it will return empty data frame. If it is not empty and consists of 1 column, then I want to add two new extra columns with "output1" and "output2". So the data frame will be either empty, or something like below:

```
   0        1        2
0  A  output1  output2
1  B  output1  output2
```

I tried something like this below:

```
if no_result = []: 
        no_result = []
        return no_result
else
        no_result[1] = 'output1'
        no_result[2] = 'output2'
        return no_result
```

it shows syntax error. How can I return the data frame? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if no_result = []` should be `if no_result == []` with **two** `=` signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'0':['A','B']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

def check_if_empty(df):
    if df.empty:
        return pd.DataFrame()
    else:
        df['output1'] = 'output1'
        df['output2'] = 'output2'
        return df

print(check_if_empty(df))

print(check_if_empty(df2))
```

I hope this helps!